# android : to use image has a map

Tags: android, image, dictionary

I have a JPEG sketch of my apartment. And I wish to write an android app which loads this JPEG file and behaves as a map to the user so that user can track is movement.

I am really confused whether a JPEG file can be used as a map, if it can, please let me know how can I mark the movement of the user on that map.

Any sample code would be really appreciated.

Comment: The GPS on a phone probably won't be accurate enough for this, particularly indoors.

Comment: This is extremely non-trivial to implement. It's definitely possible (ignoring the fact that the GPS won't work indoors), but you're recreating GPS mapping essentially from scratch. Also consider, is your sketch 100% to scale?

Comment: I dont want to rely on GPS for getting my latitude and longitude. in fact i would like to store some defined locations in a data structure and just point that locations on the image as user browses that image.

Answer (score 0):

ceejayoz is correct.  The GPS isn't going to let you track your position that accurately inside, but I can still help you with your issue.  You'll need to basically re-create the ma functionality from scratch using a view.  You can use the onDraw() method to adjust the size of the image and you can use your position from the GPS to adjust its position.You will need at the lat/lon position of at least two known points on the map to make sure that you transform it correctly.

Comment: i understand the fact that GPS wont be accurate, so i dont want to rely on GPS. assume i got set of locations predefined and i want to map that locations to pixel co-ordinates of the image, if you have some sample codes related to this, please let me know